# Vue.Js and Airtable: How to filter

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js, airtable

I am using vue.js to create a website that displays data from an Airtable "spreadsheet". I wish to create a filter function. I have a table with education information and a column to enter subject (e.g. biology, math etc.) and I would like to be able to retrieve data for only one of those, for example.

Anyone knows how I might be able to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post your code, as well as anything you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question.
Anyway, Airtable API returns an object you can filter using the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const subject = 'math';
const URL = 'your API url';
axios.get(URL).then(({ data: { records } }) => {
  this.myData = records.filter(({ fields }) => fields.subject === subject);
});
```